# Toggle between 3 plots using 2 actionButtons in a shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I have the `shiny` app below which initialy should display a plot of the `iris` dataset. If `Datatable` is pressed then it should display the datatable of `iris` dataset,if pressed again it should display the initial plot of `iris` dataset again.
If `Iris3` is pressed then it should display the plot of `iris3` dataset, if pressed again it should display the initial plot of `iris` dataset again.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      
      
      actionButton("exc",
                   "Datatable"),
      actionButton("other","Iris3")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      uiOutput(outputId = "iris_plot")
      
    )
  )
)
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  showPlot <- reactiveVal(TRUE)
  showPlotiris3 <- reactiveVal(TRUE)
  
  observeEvent(input$exc, {
    showPlot(!showPlot())
  })
  observeEvent(input$other, {
    showPlotiris3(!showPlotiris3())
  })
  output$iris_plot <- renderUI({
    if (showPlot()){
      plotOutput("plot")
    }
    else if(showPlotiris3()){
      plotOutput("plot2")
    }
    else{
      dataTableOutput("table")
    }
  })
  
  output[["plot"]] <- renderPlot({
    plot(iris)
  })
  output[["plot2"]] <- renderPlot({
    plot(iris3)
  })
  output[["table"]] <- renderDataTable(datatable(iris))
  
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      actionButton("exc","Datatable"),
      actionButton("other","Iris3")
    ),
    mainPanel( verbatimTextOutput("t1"),
      uiOutput(outputId = "iris_plot")
    )
  )
)
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  store <- reactiveValues()
  observe({store$plotrtable <- DTOutput("table")})
  
  observeEvent(input$exc, {
    if (as.numeric(input$exc) %% 2 == 1){store$plotrtable <- plotOutput("plot")
    }else store$plotrtable <- DTOutput("table")
  })
  observeEvent(input$other, {
    if (as.numeric(input$other) %% 2 == 1){store$plotrtable <- plotOutput("plot2")
    }else store$plotrtable <- DTOutput("table")
  })
  
  output[["plot"]] <- renderPlot({
    plot(iris)
  })
  output[["plot2"]] <- renderPlot({
    plot(iris3)
  })
  output[["table"]] <- renderDT(datatable(iris))

  output$iris_plot <- renderUI({
    store$plotrtable
  })
  
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```